# EF adding child entity to parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add a child entity to a parent entity. The child being `User` whilst the parent is `CheckoutToken`:

Inserting the CheckoutToken:

```
 public async Task Insert(CheckoutToken model)
 {
    var checkoutToken = new Data.Models.CheckoutToken {
        Token = model.Token,
        License = _dbContext.Licenses.Single(l => l.Id == model.License.Id),
        Created = model.Created,
        Expires = model.Expires
    };

     checkoutToken.UserId = model.User.AspNetUserId;
     checkoutToken.User = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.User.AspNetUserId);
     await _dbContext.CheckoutTokens.AddAsync(checkoutToken);
     await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

For some reason I get this exception:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (73a0c19b-a7b1-4462-8e82-12be55e47002).
The statement has been terminated.

I don't understand why it's trying to create a user?

Comment: From practice, you shouldn't be assigning objects to your models before adding/updating them like you are. Try removing the `checkoutToken.User = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.User.AspNetUserId);` and see if that helps you.

EF is smart enough to map any objects like that if the ID is referenced as a Foreign Key correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try commented this line:

```
public async Task Insert(CheckoutToken model)
 {
    var checkoutToken = new Data.Models.CheckoutToken {
        Token = model.Token,
        License = _dbContext.Licenses.Single(l => l.Id == model.License.Id),
        Created = model.Created,
        Expires = model.Expires
    };

     checkoutToken.UserId = model.User.AspNetUserId;
     // checkoutToken.User = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.User.AspNetUserId);
     await _dbContext.CheckoutTokens.AddAsync(checkoutToken);
     await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

this because you try create new user with same data of an existing, if you need assign an existing user to an new entity only assign the Id of User not the full object